# Spark parquet reading error

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am working on a Spark project, Here i had one file which is in parquet format when I try to load this file using java it gives me the below error. But when I loaded the same file in hive with the same path and write a query select * from table_name, so its working fine and data is also coming properely. Please help me regarding this issue.

> java.io.IOException: Could not read footer:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: corrupted file: the footer index is not
>   within the file   at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readAllFootersInParallel(ParquetFileReader.java:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anonfun$28.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:754)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anonfun$28.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:743)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:710)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:710)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: corrupted file: the footer index is not
>   within the file   at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:427)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:233)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)

Answer (score -4):

```
You can try below options

1)  sqlContext.read.parquet("path") 

2) sqlContext.read.format(fileFormat)
.option("header", header) // Use first line of all files as header
.option("inferSchema", inferSchema) // Automatically infer data types
.load(source)

If your issue didn't resolved, please post the sample of code.
```